# Firefox keeps input value on browser close and reopen

Tags: firefox, input

I am using an input field to store a destination value:

```
<input type="text" id="dest_location" placeholder="Enter Destination" autocomplete="off">
```

However I want to clear this value on browser reload. So after reading I found that a very simple way to do this is to add `autocomplete="off"` to the input as above.

This works really well but I noticed something unusual in the Firefox browser. When I enter a value into the input field, close the browser and reopen it the value is still saved. It is only after clicking the page reload button that the value is cleared.

I just wanted to know why this is the occurring only in the Firefox browser? I tried the same open and close browser method on Chrome, IE and Opera and the value is always cleared even before clicking on the page reload button. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Because the people who made Firefox thought it would be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have enabled saving the current tab instance in your Firefox by the option

```
    "When Firefox starts": "Show my windows and tabs from last time".
```

I've tried the similar option on google chrome which says

```
    "On Startup":"Continue where you left off".
```

But what chrome does is, it stores the URLs for the next time you reopen the browser whereas Firefox stores a copy of the current HTML too. Hence you have the data pre-filled in the textbox. Are you looking for a solution or a workaround to this?

if you are doing that

```
    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('dest_location').value="";//element to be cleared
};
```

Should fix things for you.

Comment: Hi Joey, Okay I understand what you mean. You were right I did have the Firefox option enabled to show windows and tabs from last time. Do you know if there is a solution or workaround to this problem by any chance?